# Drupal. Using administrative title as browser title

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6 and I got a lot of pages and content.
To save time, is there a way to use a page Administrative title as the title that is used in the browser (the HTML title tag: `<title>`)?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the [Page Title module](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) may be of some help to you.  It allows for more control of the html title tag by setting up title patterns using tokens made available through the [Token module](http://drupal.org/project/token)

Answer (score 1):

Drupal does this by default (at least on my install it is currently) - are you building these administration pages yourself or are they the default ones?